# Unity floating point precision when using Json strings

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im writing a program with Unity and I need to add GameObject.transform to a dictionary so I use this code....

```
Dictionary<string,object> dict=new Dictionary<string,object>();
dict["position"]=gameObject.transform.position;
```

Then later i convert the Dictionary to a Json string

```
string jsn=Json.Serialize(dict);
```

When you look at the jsn string, the position is converted to only one or two decimal places, this cause small numbers to be truncated to zero giving me lots of headache.

Is there a way to tell Json to increase the number of decimal places it uses when converting floating point to a Json string?

Thanks Very much!

Comment: It is most likely in the Json serializer using a ToString override to truncate the value. Either you modify the Json Serializer or you try another one.

Answer (score 0):

Json format badly works with a float numbers. Create your own class to work with vectors, where the double type is used, and convert it to json. Good luck!